# VLOOKUP function where 3 sheets are involved

Tags: vlookup

I have data in 2 sheets like the following:

Sheets NAMES
[image]
The sheet reports names on a daily basis

and, Sheet QUANTITY
[image]
the sheet reports quantities that correspond to each name in sheet NAMES, each day

Finally, I have a sheet NAMES & QUANTITIES
[image]
In this sheet, each day, if there is a name in sheet NAMES, I write the corresponding quantity from sheet QUANTITY, or zero otherwise.

Is there a function I can write in sheet NAMES&QUANTITY so that the values will fill automatically? For example, for cell B2 in sheet NAMES&QUANTITY, the idea is to have something like =iferror(vlookup(a2, 'NAMES'a2:a5, QUANTITY'a2:a5'), 0).
In other words, if CHRIS appears in column A in sheet NAMES, write the corresponding value from column A in sheet QUANTITY (which is 11 in the example). I know VLOOKUP does not work this way but I was wondering if there is a way to do this without running a macro.
Thank you

I haven't tried anything because I have no idea how to do this (if it can be done).